# Django: Trying to make for zip work with Python Jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Hello guys I have this code and it works perfectly in python:

```
var1 = ('puno', 'pdos', 'ptres')
var2 = ('runo', 'rdos', 'rtres')
for x, y in zip (var1, var2):
    hola = x, y
    for x in hola:
        print x
```

The output of this it's exactly what I'm looking:

```
uno
runo
pdos
rdos
ptres
rtres
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I'm trying to get the same using django with jinja but it does not work for me even If use "zip" in jinja,

Is there any way to have this result in jinja?

Let me show my code using django:

```
def todo(request):
    lista_completa = Data_pregunta.objects.all()#.order_by('id')[:2]
    lista_completa2 = Data_respuesta.objects.all()#.order_by('id')[:2]

    return render(request, 'todo.html', {'lista_completa': lista_completa,'lista_completa2':lista_completa2})
```

Jinja:

```
{% for x in lista_completa %} 

{{x.pregunta}}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

What I'm looking is to get the result of Data_pregunta then Data_respuesta, is it possible ?

I think the problem is not python is that I'm nor using jinja properly, can you guys give me a hand ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use zip() in your view.

```
listas = zip(lista_completa, lista_completa2)
return render(request, template.html, {'listas': listas})
```

Then just unpack the tuple over each oteration using two variables in a for loop.

```
{% for pregunta, respuesta in listas %}
    # pregunta.show (or whatever your attribute for pregunta is)
    # respuesta.show
{% endfor %}
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Django does not use Jinja2 templates by default. Unless you specifically configured Django to use Jinja2, you're using the Django template language (which has a very similar syntax).

Django's template engine doesn't have any nice way to do this. You just need to `zip` the two `QuerySet`s before passing them into the template:

```
return render(request, 'todo.html', {
    'preguntas_y_respuestas': zip(lista_completa, lista_completa2)
})
```

In your template, you can iterate over the pairs of objects:

```
{% for pregunta, respuesta in preguntas_y_respuestas %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```